# sending path and xml filename to xmlreader

Tags: c#, xml

I am working in C# on VS 2010. I am trying to send a path and file name to xmlreader.  I was able to get it to read properly when the xml file was in the same directory as the exe file using this:

```
string fname =  "APIKeyInfoApi." + KEY + ".0.xml";

label4.Text = Convert.ToString(aa.ReturnCharID(fname));
```

and here is the method I am using to process the part of the xml document I want.

```
public int ReturnCharID(string fname)
    {
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fname);
        int myID = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "row")
            {
               myID = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetAttribute(0));
            }
        }
        return myID;
    }
```

As I said earlier this all works fine when the xml file is in the same directory as my program but I have been trying to get it to read from another directory which in this case is a folder located in my userprofile.  I was trying with xml text reader but I was receiving exceptions for full path.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you write a fname value for which the reader doesn't work?

Comment: I was trying this earlier

    string cachelist =  string EVECM_cache = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\EVECM\") + fname;

then I would naturally change fname on the method to cachelist.

Comment: Can you test the return value of this: System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\EVECM\") + fname)

Comment: Yes I can return that.  It returns the path and the filename.

Comment: sorry misread the question, The file in question already exists. For the testing I copied it over to where I want to read it from.

Comment: So I ran your code: System.IO.File.Exists(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\App‌​Data\Local\EVECM\") + fname) in an if statement and it returned false.  I checked the folder and the file does indeed exist.

Comment: If File.Exists returned false, then path to file is not well formed. Instead of using ExpandEnvironmentVariables, try to put a constant string with full path to the file. If that works fine, then compare that constant string to whatever is obtained by Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERPROFILE%\App‌​‌​Data\Local\EVECM\") + fname.

Comment: fair enough. I double checked the exception that is thrown and the error is System.IO Possible Full path? with the entire path listed from C:\ up to the file.

Comment: Figured it out it was indeed a simple mistake on my part.